# Read from a text file and order the rows (each row int + String)

Tags: c#, file, archive, bookmarks

I'm coding a game for a university project similar to Subway Surfers. I have everything working precisely but my problem comes in a bookmarks option I coded.

When you lose in the game you have to enter a name and this is written and saved on a text file in the format `<int score> <string name>`, for example:

```
11245 Lucas
10123 Marco
 2394 Ricky
```

So then in the menu of the game you can select bookmarks and the text file is read and shown on the screen one score under the other with the name that was written in each game.

Now my problem is that I want the bookmarks to be ordered, with the highest on top, but I do not know how I can do that as I have an int and a string in each line and they are related therefore I can't have one file for the scores and one file for the names as therefore when I order the scores I lost the info regarding who achieved each score.

What can I do to solve this?

EDIT:
I'm adding the part of the code related to my question.
This is the method that shows the bookmarks

```
static void ReadBookmark()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("BOOKMARKS");
            string myfile = @"bookmarks.txt";
            if (File.Exists(myfile) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("NO BOOKMARKS. PLAY SOME GAMES!");
                Console.Write("\nPRESS A KEY TO RETURN...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(myfile))
                {
                    string s = "";
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\t{s}");
                    }
                }
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("\n\nPRESS A KEY TO RETURN...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

And here is the code where the name and score are written on the file.

```
public void SaveBookmark(int score, string name)
        {
            string myfile = @"bookmarks.txt";
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(myfile))
            {
                sw.WriteLine($"{score} {name}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: show your current code

Comment: I just added it

Answer (score 3):

You can split each line on whitespace and then use `int.Parse` to get the numeric value of the first part, and then `OrderByDescending` using that value:

```
var orderedLines = File.ReadLines(myfile)
    .OrderByDescending(line => int.Parse(line.Split()[0]))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Full example of what to do safely, finished before you posted your code.
This will allow the names to have a space in them.

```
public List<ScoreItem> GetScores()
{
    var scoreList = new List<ScoreItem>();
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead("myPath"))
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;

            var scoreMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"\A\d*");
            if (!scoreMatch.Success)
                throw new Exception($"Failed to parse score from line [{line}].");

            var nameMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<!\A\d*).*\Z");
            if (!nameMatch.Success)
                throw new Exception($"Failed to parse name from line [{line}].");

            if (!int.TryParse(scoreMatch.Value, out var score))
                throw new Exception($"Failed to cast score to a number from line [{line}].");

            scoreList.Add(new ScoreItem {Name = nameMatch.Value, Score = score});
        }

        return scoreList.OrderByDescending(s => s.Score).ToList();
    }
}

public class ScoreItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Very usefull, im gonna try. Thank you very much